# Java Connecting of Client SSLSocket with selfsigned JKS certificate

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl

I am using Java jdk/jre6 with Eclipse and struggling with a problem connecting my applications client SSLSocket to a SSL server.

I would much appreciate any help dealing with this as I am stuck.

I have created a self signed jks using key-tool and set the System properties and create an SSL socket

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:/.../mystore.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","thepassword");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:/.../mystore.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","thepassword");
SSLSocket sslsocket= (SSLSocket) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket(ip,port);
```

However when I try my first socket write  I get an exception thrown.

```
socket.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes(),0,message.length());

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1358)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.available(AppInputStream.java:40)
at com.guiink.mbt.MbtFixApi.readFixMessage(MbtFixApi.java:181)
at com.guiink.gui.GuiWnd$FixConnection$1.run(GuiWnd.java:766)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
at com.guiink.gui.GuiWnd.open(GuiWnd.java:141)
at com.guiink.gui.GuiWnd.main(GuiWnd.java:118)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1764)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:241)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:235)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1206)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:136)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:958)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1203)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:654)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:100)
at com.guiink.mbt.MbtFixApi.writeToServer(MbtFixApi.java:1481)
at com.guiink.mbt.MbtFixApi.sendFixMessage(MbtFixApi.java:1437)
at com.guiink.mbt.MbtFixApi.createFixSession(MbtFixApi.java:150)
at com.guiink.gui.GuiWnd.open(GuiWnd.java:135)
... 1 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:323)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:217)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1185)
... 12 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:174)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:318)
... 18 more
```

Can anyone please show me the cause/correction of my error?

Comment: you didn't forget to add the server's certificate to the keystore, or did you?

Comment: The problem is `unable to find valid certification path to requested target` look for this [QUESTION](http://example.com) maybe helpful for you

Comment: Thanks for the reply piet.t, no I have not, can I add an selfsigned certificate from a server using stunnel to mystore.jks using keytool?